# Multiple statement in if elseif powershell with equal with or doesn't work

Tags: windows, powershell

I can't find what is the issue with the 2 (SIN and SHA) lines in the below if else statement where have -or also.
I've tried with -xor, tried with separate the or conditions with multiple elseif to separate lines, but doesn't work from remote command.

```
if($site -eq 'HKG1') {...}
elseif($site -eq 'AMS1') {...}
elseif( ($site -eq 'SIN1') -or ($site -eq 'SIN3') ) {...}
elseif( ($site -eq 'SHA1') -or ($site -eq 'SHA2') -or ($site -eq 'SHA3') ) {...}
elseif($site -eq 'ASH1') {...}
```

If I try this way:

```
if($site -eq 'HKG1') {...}
elseif($site -eq 'AMS1') {...}
elseif($site -eq 'SIN1' -or 'SIN3') {...}
elseif($site -eq 'SHA1' -or 'SHA2' -or 'SHA3') {...}
elseif($site -eq 'ASH1') {...}
```

it works in some scenario but if has to go to AMS it will land in SIN and fails.

Comment: `-or` expects a boolean expression on each side and will evaluate to `$true` if _either_ operand does. `[bool]'SIN3'` evaluates to `$true`, so `$site -eq 'SIN1' -or 'SIN3'` is no different from writing `$site -eq 'SIN1' -or $true`, which in turn is no different than simply writing `$true` :) You probably want `$site -like 'SIN*'`

Comment: `'SHA1', 'SHA2', 'SHA3' -eq $Site` [When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen answered my question

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to investigate switch instead multiple if

```
switch ($x)
{
    'value1' {}
    {$_ -in 'A','B','C'} {}
    'value3' {}
    Default {}
}
```